# Android : Avoid children background cover parent's one in xml

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, children

I have a bad UI bug that I can't resolve.
In a Coordinatorlayout, I have to display expandable layout with a 1 dp round border, a header and content. However, when I set a background color to header or content, it overlap the parent's background, hiding the border.
In picture 1, you can see what I want and in picture 2 what I obtain .

**picture 1**

[image: picture 1]

**picture 2**

[image: picture 2]

This layout above is not expandable to simplify, but I always get the same result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/missionDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mission_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMission"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mission"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDetail"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/detail"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMission" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non vulputate mi. Suspendisse augue ipsum, suscipit vel mattis aliquet, cursus sit amet dolor. Cras id ante ac justo sollicitudin posuere nec a risus. Maecenas vulputate dictum dui, eu tempor urna rhoncus nec. Vivamus et erat eu eros rutrum mattis. Morbi tincidunt nunc in ultricies ornare. Nulla sed ornare dolor. In consequat, purus at suscipit bibendum, quam nisi hendrerit dolor, eget tempor lacus metus in odio. Nulla faucibus maximus libero, ut scelerisque lacus imperdiet id. Aenean vel tincidunt est."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I prefer to add that many of these layout are longer, so I can't do a top round border background for the header, and bottom round border for the content.
How to always display the parent's border ? Please, help me

Answer (score 1):

You want to change `backgroundTint` not `background`. Replacing the background removes all intrinsic properties and replaces it with the given `background` which is just a color. If you're  on API level less than 21. You can set this in code via `ColorFilter` or your can make an XML style and apply it to the `ConstraintLayout`